# What is the equivlent function of "windowsFonts" or "windowsFont" in R for Ubuntu?

Tags: r, fonts

To deal with font in windows with R, currently I am using "windowsFont" and "windowsFont" but what function I should use for Ubuntu 14.04?

code snippet:

```
windowsFonts(t = windowsFont(ttf))
text(50, 20, words[word], family = "t", cex=3)
```

Comment: Presumably you're using that function because you read the documentation that explains how to load a font so... just read that same documentation more? Surely it covers more than just "windows". (a quick google search shows at least two packages that add easy font loading to R, I assume you tried both of those so: how did those not work for you?)

Comment: Wouldn't the obvious answer be to look at `?X11Fonts`? I think the canonical starting point for graphics output would be `?Devices`. There is an entry for `X11` on that page and then follow the link to `X11Fonts`.